# What is the equivalent to $HOME in a virtualenv (python) - specifically for matplotlibrc

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv

I have found this beautiful [ggplot inspired color scheme for matplotlib](http://www.huyng.com/posts/sane-color-scheme-for-matplotlib/) and want to use it for a specific project.

As per the matplotlib documentation, custom color scheme should not overwrite the default in `site-packages` but instead be placed in `$HOME/.matplotlib`. But what is the equivalent for `$HOME`in a `venv`? Specifically: how can I make sure this color scheme is not overwritten when installing/upgrading a new `matplotlib`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason why you don't want to just save it under your actual `$HOME` directory?

Virtualenv is a tool for creating isolated *Python* environments. As such, it does not try to provide a whole user environment. So basically, the `$HOME` of a virtualenv is just the normal `$HOME` of the user.

As for as Matplotlib goes, the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html) mentions how the `matplotlibrc` file is searched for:

1. First, it **looks for a `matplotlibrc` in the current direcotry**. This may be a candidate location for your venv-specific configurations.
2. Second, it looks in the user's configuration (`~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`).
3. Last, it looks in the install directory.

Comment: Hmmm - no specific reason in this case. But I could imagine having different projects with different color schemes. But maybe there is a option for sourcing different colorschemes, directly from the code. Just haven't found it.

Comment: Maybe this is a matplotlib question more than it's a `venv`question. Any ways - I am not completely sure the question is answered, so will wait a litlle while before I give you the green check mark :-)

Comment: @Andreas: I'm not sure if it will answer your question, but I added some more information that I could find in regards to configuring Matplotlib.

Comment: Yes :-) Thank you for clearing that up for me. - accepted :-)

Answer (score 0):

After accepting Voithos answer, I found MPLtools, which assists:

> A key feature of mpltools is the ability to set “styles”—essentially, stylesheets that are similar to matplotlibrc files. This example demonstrates the “ggplot” style, which adjusts the style to emulate ggplot

Posting here for posterity :-)

http://tonysyu.github.com/mpltools/auto_examples/style/plot_ggplot.html